Windows 10 builtin IKEv2 VPN does not have option for preshared key
I configured Routing and Remote Access on Windows Server 2019, then built-in VPN Type IKEv2 + PSK:

Filled the PSK in "Allow custom IPsec policy for L2TP/IKEv2 connection" (rrasmgmt.msc)
Firewall ports are opened for IPSEC

Now I'm creating a new VPN connection on Windows  10, but, there is not a "pre-shared key" option when I choose the "IKev2" VPN type.
What's wrong?
